# ViewModel vs static variable in an activity

Tags: android

I know that one of the solutions to handle orientation change is to use ViewModel to hold the data as it outlives the activity.

However, I was wondering, can't we achieve the same thing if we create a static variable in the class to hold the same data?

Why would we go down the ViewModel path?

Thanks

Comment: Why would anyone downvote a question? if it is too easy for you, it might not be for others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! So, could we achieve the same? Probably yes, but it will be like re-inventing the wheel, and also you'll most likely end up into the same, or a similar, solution as the ViewModel provides. What I guess you need to understand here is that activities in Android are reflections of an underlying [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design, whereas the data information you bind to your activities are decoupled from the view themselves, so that at any point in time you can re-bind your actual data state to the view (the activity) recreating it, and therefore continuing like nothing was changed. For instance upon a screen rotation, where your activity (view) is destroyed, given its data state is saved and passed, and then recreated, its data re-binded and user can continue from where she left.
That's what ViewModel does, it manages the activity data state in the context of Android lifecycle. If you would like to accomplish the same yourself, it will be very difficult but possible.

Comment: I upvoted it for the explanation but didn't provide an example where one would fail or make it cumbersome like the accepted answer. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @Snake , if you're familiar with the MVC pattern, well an example is pretty straight forward, right? You've 2 instances of the same view, but you want each to have a separate state. Otherwise you would have no need for MVC in first place. The same applies also to any widget you use on each activity, not only to activities. I think the important part here is to understand the underlying Android design, the architectural choices which were thought thoroughly and made consciously when Android 1.0 was released. Next time you want people to provide an example as well, ask it in your question :)

Comment: @Snake note: I also upvoted your question, which was -1 before, because I think it's a very interesting question, and I wish there will be more of these questions on SO, instead of people just asking "can you make my homework please please please" ... questions like this are a good indicator, that you're really thinking about the framework you use, and you're willing to know it better. I really respect such questions :)

Comment: Your ellaborated comment provided a generic example where it could fail and that was good.And thank you for your  insight. Yes I don't like to apply things blindly without know the rational or cases where one might /might not work

Answer (score 4):

One reason is because Activities themselves aren't static or singletons.  You can have an ItemViewActivity launch another ItemViewActivity for a different item, and if they're sharing the same variables via statics you've probably just broke the back button.  And if you don't code them very carefully you're probably going to send data to the wrong Activity's views.

Comment: Interesting , I forgot about the case of reusing activities for different purposes

Answer (score 1):

Static variable will always exist throughout the lifecycle of the application. If you don't clean it up in time, memory may be wasted.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModel` library in one of the `Android architecture components` and apart from handling configuration changes, it also acts as a mode of communication between `Activity/Fragment` and data access layer of your application. This data access layer may include your cache, `SQLite` or any other remote data over cloud.
Associating `ViewModel` with `LiveData` can do lot of other things.
Refer to a [sample here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3).